# What happens if I use lower amperage in "input"?

Tags: repair, charging, ac-adapter

I have problem now. I want to ask what happened.
I bought new charger for my HP compaq nc6400.
My charger stats...

```
60W
Input : 100V-240V~1.7A
Output : 18,5V = 3,5 A
(HP supported)
```

I used....

```
90W
Input: 100V-240V ~ 2.0A
Output: 19V = 4.74A
```

(When I put this charger it worked perfect and performance was a lot better)
New charger...

```
Input: 100V-240V ~ 1.5A
Output: 19V = 4.74A
```

(After I bought this new charger and put it in, my Laptop smelled like something inside is burning... Well, nothing smelled like burning when u try to smell keyboard, or display. It was right where u put in AC adapter.)

I used bouth of theese 2 chargers (older ones - 90W and 60W) . They worked perfect.
Now, I desided to bouth new, because my 90W charger was in repair. Everything was fine. In describe was nc6400, so I bought it. I checked everything and compared bouth of theese 2 chargers and I tried to buy charger, what Is almoust same like that one.

May I know reason, why now PC isnt working? May I also know what can be broken inside of it and what can I do?

Comment: By the way James, thanks for reply. No, polarity was right... May I know what can be damaged? There was smoke a bit and small "boom". I also put in charger, what worked fine, and laptop wasnt turning on.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the amps meets the device's minimum required to run, then lower amps generally shouldn't cause a major problem. For a laptop charger I could see it not having enough power to actually charge the battery, but still running OK or maybe slowly draining the battery (as if it weren't plugged into a charger).

If the amps were too low (and there were no battery) then the device probably won't turn on, or might try turning on & fail repeatedly.

But you let the [magic smoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_smoke) out - it won't work anymore :( If you took apart your laptop you'll probably find a burnt or blackened part that has failed or exploded. [Capacitors can explode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WheLp0RdLQ)... but could've damaged other less obvious parts too.

You might still be able to test the power adapter (if it still works) with a multimeter and see how many volts it's outputting and if the polarity is right. Using a small test light / light bulb as a small load might help - I saw a power adapter ("wall wart") once that would output 20V with no load, but when plugged in it read 14V, but it seemed bad & was replaced anyway.